Missing Camunda pods metrics of EKS Container Insights running on managed nodes
We have installed camunda on managed nodes in an eks cluster. However we could not make a chart widget using metrics from custom namespace of ContainerInsights. The namespace under which these camunda pods are located, does not show up in the search.
ec2-fluentbit has been installed in amazon-cloudwatch namespace. Fluent bit logs can been seen in cloud watch
adot-collector is installed in ns-fargate-container-insights namespace
Does Container insights provide metrics for pods on managed nodes in eks cluster?
Is it mandatory to install CloudWatch Observability EKS add-on?
We cannot use EC2 metrics as the ec2 instance ids will change during scaling
Thanks
Sameer

You better provide your installation and config or which scripts that you have been used for collecting metrics. Else, it's hard to say that why there is no metrics. Usually, the metrics even from other namespaces should be there.

I have ec2-fluentbit installed in amazon-cloudwatch namespace. The camuda pods are under the the ec2-app namespace. Using containerInsights I can access metrics for all namespaces on fargate type node except ec2-app which is on managed nodes

Fluentbit is used for sending logs to CWLogs I assume, not related to metrics. From those nodes, do they have the cwagent running along in each node or not?

Yes, you are right, Fluentbit is used to send logs to cloudwatch and not related to metrics. The cw agent is not installed as a sidecar in camunda pods (which I need metrics for). However When i checked other pods which show up in container Insights metrics, they too do not have cw agent as sidecar. All the pods  which show in containerInsights metrics have launch type fargate

Also we have adot-collector installed in ns-fargate-container-insights namespace.

I mentioned above, it should be running at Node level, not at each Pod except you run it as 2nd container of that Pod for specific usecase. Whatever agent that you are using, ensure that its daemonset to be running at each Node so that it can perform collecting things based on its function.
